# ObjectOutputStream writing extra characters

Tags: java, file, outputstream, writer

I know that writers should be used instead of outputstreams when writing text, but still I don't understand why there are extra characters in the file `outputStream.txt` after running this program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Data\\tmp\\outputStream.txt")));
        oos.writeObject("SomeObject");
        oos.writeUTF("SomeUTF");
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Data\\tmp\\outputWriter.txt")));
        writer.write("SomeObject");
        writer.write("SomeUTF");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
```

The file `outputWriter.txt` is 17bytes, as expected, but `outputStream.txt` is 28, including some unrecognizable text. Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ObjectOutputStream` is used to write Java objects to a stream. That means won't write the value of a String into the stream; instead if will write "the next object is a `String` and the value for it is `SomeObject`".

So if you want a plain text file, you have to use the `Writer` API.

Note: Your code is platform dependent. If you want to make it platform independent, then you have to use:

```
    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream( file );
    return new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( stream, Charset.forName("UTF-8") ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

`outputStream.txt` file contains the binary (stream) format of your "SomeObject" as in Object Serialization. This can be read back as your original object using `ObjectInputStream`.This is called de-serialization process.

However, `BufferedWriter` write the data in text format has nothing to do with serialization. So while reading back you need to read the text and you have to re-create your object manually.

Comment: Is there any way to remove those extra bytes..?

Comment: why you want to do so, anyways seems its a different question? Please ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

An ObjectOutputStream writes binary data.

From the API:

```
public void writeUTF(String str) throws IOException
```

> Primitive data write of this String in modified UTF-8 format.

The extra bytes are probably coming from the modified UTF-8 encoding.